# type is invalid -- expected a string, react-native error

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I'm new at React-Native. I'm trying to build an app on mobile. But when I run this code I'm getting this error: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components). My App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

import { Header } from './components/Header';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Header title="guess a number"/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen:{
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

My Header.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const Header = props => {
    return(
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.headerTitle}> {props.title}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    header: {

        width:'100%',
        height:90,
        paddingTop: 36,
        backgroundColor:'#f7287b',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'

    },
    headerTitle: {
        color:'black',
        fontSize: 18
    }
});

export default Header;
```

What should i do?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYgSh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import of Header component is wrong. Import it as such :

`import Header from './components/Header';`

This is because you've exported as default in your Header.js File, so you need to import directly without `{}` brackets

Comment: Hey, I just checked on my device and it worked completely fine. Please update your question including the screenshot of the error

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:
`<Header title={'guess a number'}/>`